# Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?

Tags: solidity, web3js, safemoon

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

I have implemented the safemoon contract but when I deployed the code in the BSC testnet it's given me an error.

```
contract SafemoonDemo is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
   
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tTotal = 1000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;

    string private _name = "SafeMoonDemo";
    string private _symbol = "SFD";
    uint8 private _decimals = 9;
    
    uint256 public _taxFee = 5;
    uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
    
    uint256 public _liquidityFee = 5;
    uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
    
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
    
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 5000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    uint256 private numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = 5000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    
    event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
    );
    
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }
    
    constructor () public {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
         // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        // set the rest of the contract variables
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        
        //exclude owner and this contract from fee
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is trying to call the `factory()` function on the `0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E` address, expecting a 20-byte response that it would convert to an `address` type.

Even though there is the [PancakeSwap router](https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E#code) contract deployed on this address on the BSC mainnet, the BSC testnet [doesn't hold any contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E) on this address.

So your constructor fails as it doesn't get the 20-byte response (from the non-contract address) that it expects.

The Pancakeswap [docs page](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/smart-contracts) doesn't list any testnet addresses, so it's possible that there are no official Pancakeswap contracts on the testnet.

Comment: But i used rinkeby testnet so it gave me this error. 

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted

Comment: @NiteshMehra I was under the impression that you tested the code on BSC testnet as your question states. However, there is [no contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E) on this address on Rinkeby either. So it's the same reason.

Comment: Thank you @Petr Hejda you gave me a suggestion but if we want to deploy the safemoon Contract to mainnet so we use this address 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E
but if we test the safemoon contract on the BSC test net so used this address 0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1.